# Get cursor position when all application forms are out of focus

Tags: c#

I was trying to create a program for displaying mouse cursor movements by creating pictures based on the movements. The problem is, the application requires to be able to detect and track mouse movement even when unfocused/minimized.

So far, I've been trying to use many different approaches, such as global mouse hooks. The code for the MouseMove event is below (sp= starting point, ep= ending point):

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (k == 0)
        {
            ep = e.Location;
            g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawLine(p, sp, ep);
        }
        sp = ep;
    }
```

This code only works to track mouse movement when the form is focused and only movement over the form. There is another way where I managed to track movement outside the form, but it stops working when the form's size changes.

What is the proper/best way to track movement using a global mouse hook or similar?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you will probably run in to this later based on your example code; if you ever find yourself calling `.CreateGraphics` you are probably doing something wrong 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently on my cell phone but will do my best to get it correct for you.

You can do this by calling one of the native functions from the user32.dll class.

Put this in your class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);
```

And then use it like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
       Point cursorPos;
       GetCursorPos(out cursorPos);
}
```

The cursorPos will have the X and Y position of your mouse.

Comment: I'd give you bonus points just for the way you managed to format that text from a cell phone keyboard.

Comment: I'm just curious about one thing: Why are you doing the WinAPI calls yourself when there's a [**`Cursor.Position`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: @VisualVincent Two reasons. I believe everyone should be introduced to WinAPI calls and he can use this anywhere without having to reference System.Windows.Forms :)